# Looking for advice on “subscribing” to a user

Tags: email, postmaster, notification, subscriptions

I'm building my very first EE website and I am looking for some advice regarding email notifications based on user activity. I would like members to be able to “subscribe” to or "follow" other members such that when a member posts an article or uploads a document, anyone subscribed to that user will get an email notification. It looks like Postmaster might be a step in the right direction? Are there any other suggestions on how to get me started? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest checking out the [Friends](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/friends) module from Solspace. It has a lot of this functionality built in. I'm not sure about the email notifications though, so you'll have to research that part, and if it doesn't do it natively, I'm positive Postmaster can help with that.